# Select rows with specific value for a column if present

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql table t1 with columns c1, c2, c3, c4,.. cn. Primary key is a composite key with columns(c1, c2,c3,...).
One of the primary key columns c1 can have only 2 values v1 or v2. I need to write a query such that all other key columns being same select the row containing v2 if v2 is present else select the row containing v1.

I tried partition_by clause with row_number() but for large data set it will create too many partitions so not feasible.

Comment: The `row_number()` analytic function to identify the first row in each group is exactly what I'd use to solve your requirement. Your comment of "too many partitions" doesn't make sense; the data doesn't end up being physically partitioned, just allocated into groups. Would you complain about too many groups if you were doing an aggregate function (e.g. `count()` or `max()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and `PARTITION BY` all the columns in the primary key except for `c1` and then `ORDER BY c1` in `DESC`ending order and then filter to only return the rows that are numbered first in each partition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY c2, c3, c4, c5 -- All the primary key columns except c1
           ORDER BY c1 DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```